# Compatibility between AesJS and C# System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, node.js, aes

I'm developing an application in **NodeJS** that consums a **C# API**. And I want to implement securized calls with **AES**. I'm using [AesJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js) in **NodeJS** and [System.Security.Cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netframework-4.7.2) in **C#**.

The **C#** part is used in other parts of the application and works correctly, so I'm guessing my error is in the **NodeJS** part.

The error is:

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

My code:

**NodeJS**

```
encryptData = function(data) {
    var key = pbkdf2.pbkdf2Sync(config.aes.pass, config.aes.salt, 1, 128 / 8, null);
    var dataBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(data);
    var ivBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(config.aes.iv);
    var aesOfb = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ofb(key, ivBytes);
    var encryptedBytes = aesOfb.encrypt(dataBytes);
    var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);

    return encryptedHex;
}
```

**C#**

```
public static string DecodeAndDecrypt(string encrypted)
{
    using (var csp = Aes.Create())
    {
        var d = GetCryptoTransform(csp, false);
        byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        byte[] decryptedOutput = d.TransformFinalBlock(output, 0, output.Length);
        string decypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedOutput);
        return decypted;
    }
}
```

The error happens in this line:

> byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);

**UPDATE**

In order to test what's commented, I added parse to base64 in **NodeJS**:

```
return Buffer.from(encryptedHex).toString('base64');
```

Now I'm getting one step ahead into:

> byte[] decryptedOutput = d.TransformFinalBlock(output, 0, output.Length);

And it returns error:

> The input data is not a complete block.

Comment: Can you add details about the exception you are getting ?

Comment: It really doesn't say much more. I can post the StackTrace if you want.

Comment: I'm not sure `aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes()` produces Base64 encoding - it just converts to hexadecimal which is not the same thing.

Comment: It's the way documentation says it's used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js#ofb---output-feedback

Comment: That document makes no mention of Base64 encoding. In fact the example it gives shows the output`"55e3af2638c560b4fdb9d26a630733ea60197ec23deb85b1f60f71f10409ce27"` which is hex not Base64.

Comment: So, you say there's a step missed: convert the hex in Base64 before send it, right? I'm newbie in securization.

Comment: I don't think you need to convert to hex at all, you just need to convert `encryptedBytes` to Base64. I assume `encryptedBytes` is a byte array. I'm not familiar with node js or aesjs, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm following the documentation since I'm also not familiar with AesJS. But it doesn't seems to work as easy as it's shown.